# What does $C^{-3}$ mean?

Tags: matrices

If $C$ is a matrix, what does $C^{-3}$ mean?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$ C^{-3} = (C^{-1})^3=C^{-1} C^{-1} C^{-1}$$

Comment: yeap. that's what I thought but when I checked the solutions. the answer for M1. was 0.001783 . thus that make sense? Shouldn't it be a matrix?

Comment: parsiad  Please do not use `\Huge` to render your answer a montrocity.

Comment: @GabrielVizcaya what is M1? What solutions are you referring to? If you have a full question that your current one stems from, you should ask the full question and include your thoughts on what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Alternatively, it makes just as much sense to say $C^{-3} = (C^3)^{-1}.$  That is, it is the inverse of the matrix $C^3$.

Comment: @Tyberius: OP posted this before I edited it out of his question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16vjS.png

Comment: @Tyberius if you check the image I put as a link.  M.1 says compute C^(-3) but the answer the book gives is   0.001783. but I don´t understand what does it mean? The answer should be a matrix for all I know.

Comment: @GabrielVizcaya the instructions of the question ask you to write the element in the 2nd row, 3rd column position, so the solution is just for that, not the whole matrix.